# How do you delete a sharedPreference by clicking on a listView item?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences, android-adapter

I have created a list that displays a shared preference as a string. I create it like this...

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);


if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name0)) {
    String prefs = sharedpreferences.getString(Name0, "");
    listItems.add(prefs);
}
```

and so on with other preferences. I am trying to figure out how to delete a list item, and the shared preference along with it as well. I can't figure out if I should use an onClick listener, or a delete button in the list or some other method I perhaps haven't read about. I'd like to make it very simple and intuitive for the user.

So my question is, how can I edit my existing code to delete a list item and the preference that it is displaying. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote? I'd like to know so I could edit my question or phrase it a little better.

Comment: How you decide to delete the list view item is down to you :) However to remove the corresponding shared preference you can call sharedpreferences.edit().remove(Name0).commit();

Comment: But say I had an onClickListener that would delete a list-item once selected, how could I pass the desired shared preference such as name0 or name1, to execute the code you provided above? @Losin'Me

Comment: One suggestion would be using setTag(). Put the name0 for example on the tag of the button used to remove the list item. Then in the onClickListener() { onClick(View v) { ... } }  you can use v.getTag() to "identify" that button and remove the shared preference. If you're attaching the onClickListener in the list view adapter, do NOT set the tag where you initialize the convertView (convertView == null) as then you'll have the wrong names attached.

Comment: Okay, so in order to use this method you described, I would have to use an individual button for each list item that way I could use setTag() to send the parameter to my onClickListener? @Losin'Me

Comment: You have several options how to remove list items. You could add a `Button`, as you mentioned. Another common way is to use an item long clock to bring up a menu from where you can delete it. Use `onCreateContextMenu()` for that. If you wanna be really sophisticated, you could let the user swipe the item to the left for deleting it. You had to google this one up though.

Comment: And btw: do not use `commit()` for the shared preferences in the UI thread, because it is blocking. Use `apply()` instead, that is async.

Comment: @SimonSays Thanks for responding. As I am only starting out in android development, how intuitive are these approaches for users? Would users know to long click a list item to bring up a menu? If I were to use a single button, I would have to use some sort of Checkbox or something to select items. It just seems there are too many way to approach this and it seems as if there is not a standard for list item deletion that users could easily recognize.

Comment: That is correct yes, you would have to create a custom list view item layout and adapter if you wish to take the button approach. As Simon suggested there is the setOnItemClickListener or setOnItemLongClickListener, which will give you the index of the item in the list which then you can use the index of the item to match up to the name of the item you wish to delete :)

Comment: I would say using a long click on list items is a fairly common use case in Android, so users should be used to that. Nevertheless, I would let them know about this in some way. Many apps show some sort of transparent tutorial the first time you open it that tells you about how to use it.

Comment: @SimonSays, I posted up the solution that I worked on over the weekend if you would like to see it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Losin'Me check out the comment above

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up figuring out over the weekend, it takes a shared preference which has two values that are comma separated. Ex. (Wifiname_SSID,John's Wifi). It then splits up the shared preference values, and checks to see if the shared preference values match the string that is stored in the list. If the shared preference and the list item that is clicked match, then the item is deleted.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                NicknamePrefs.this);
        adb.setTitle("Delete?");
        adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete \n"
                + adapter.getItem(position));
        final int positionToRemove = position;
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String item = adapter.getItem(positionToRemove);
                List<String> items = Arrays.asList(item
                        .split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(positionToRemove));

                String prefs1 = sharedpreferences.getString(Name0, "");
                List<String> items1 = Arrays.asList(prefs1
                        .split("\\s*,\\s*"));


                if (item.contains(items1.get(0))
                        || item.contains(items1.get(1))) {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().remove(Name0).apply();
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        adb.show();
    }
});
```